# Excel formula with named range

Tags: excel-formula, named-ranges

I have a question about formulas, it´s not an easy one, I hope someone can solve it.

Table looks like this

```
Idx Val Rslt
1   1   3
1   2   3
1   3   3
2   11  13
2   12  13
2   13  13
```

Named range NR encapsulates columns Idx and Val (without headers).

I would like to have a formula for Rslt column cells that :

a) recognizes rows with same Idx value

b) returns max Val from that set of rows

I hope I was clear, if not - feel free to ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$B$2:$B$7))`

Type this in to C2 and then press **ctrl+shift+enter**, it will then fill the formula down.

Comment: Ok, you are assuming that first row is empty. Unfortunately your formula gives 13 instead of 3 as first result. I did it other way, it's maybe complicated but it works here, formula is : =MAX(INDEX((INDEX(A2:B7,0, 1)=A2)*(INDEX(A2:B7,0, 2)),0))    --- Thanks!

Comment: @Milan It gives 13 if you don't create the aray by pressing ctrl+shift+enter when you get some time do some research on ctrl+shift+enter it may save you some time on future issues instead of using slightly more complexed index formula's.  Also don't forget to use absolute values ($) so that you can easily copy your formula down.  Good luck!

Comment: I though CSE will "fill the formula down" was used to copy the formula in the cells below. Sorry for misunderstanding. I just tried it and it works perfect. And I am reading about CSE formulas, great stuff, I will surely use them in the future. Thanks a million !!!